# How to parse this kind of json String in ios

Tags: ios, json, parsing

Hello I am newbie to ios programming and learning things i am going through making webservice call and fetching response in json format.I succeed this one but i dont know how to fetch(parse) the response and looping through the response.My response is as below and my dictionary is as below:
**json**

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c201",
                "name": "Johnny Depp",
                "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c202",
                "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio",
                "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c203",
                "name": "John Wayne",
                "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c204",
                "name": "Angelina Jolie",
                "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c205",
                "name": "Dido",
                "email": "dido@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c206",
                "name": "Adele",
                "email": "adele@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c207",
                "name": "Hugh Jackman",
                "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c208",
                "name": "Will Smith",
                "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c209",
                "name": "Clint Eastwood",
                "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2010",
                "name": "Barack Obama",
                "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2011",
                "name": "Kate Winslet",
                "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "female",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        {
                "id": "c2012",
                "name": "Eminem",
                "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        }
    ]
}



 **code**

 NSString *mydata = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"====My data from webservice is===%@",mydata);


     NSError *e = nil;
    //saving data in dictionary.
    NSDictionary *recipeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
        NSLog(@"My Dictionary is %@", recipeDictionary);
```

Comment: Did you try searching this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple.

According to your response it is confirmed that your response is a dictionary.and in your recipeDictionary there a array object associated with contacts key.

So take this value in array.Like this

```
 NSArray *yourContactsArray = [recipeDictionary valueForKey:@"contacts"];
```

Now this array contains the multiple objects which are in form of dictionary.I am printing all the values in name key to demonstrate you fetching.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in yourContactsArray)
{
     NSString *name = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
     NSLog(@"%@",name);
}
```

Comment: if you have any question then please ask

Comment: Never use `valueForKey:` / `setValue:forKey:` unless you **really** need the KVC functionality. The dedicated method to get a value by key is `objectForKey:`.

Comment: Hi..having a question

Comment: I want to passing the values to another screen in storyboard using segue,but i cant.pls help me for this.

Comment: you want to pass values in storyboard . . . So what problem you are facing , tell me

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to create a model class for storing data from web services. Name the class as Contact

**Contact.h**

```
@interface Contact : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *contactId;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *gender;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *mobilePhone;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *homePhone;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *officePhone;

@end
```

In your Contact.m file

```
@implementation Contacts



- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dict{

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        //Parse your dictionary into objects here
        _contactId = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
        _email = [dict objectForKey:@"email"];
        _name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        _address = [dict objectForKey:@"address"];
        _gender = [dict objectForKey:@"gender"];
        _homePhone = [[dict objectForKey:@"phone"] objectForKey:@"home"];
        _mobilePhone = [[dict objectForKey:@"id"] objectForKey:@"mobile"];
        _officePhone = [[dict objectForKey:@"id"] objectForKey:@"office"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In your class

```
NSString *mydata = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"====My data from webservice is===%@",mydata);
NSError *e = nil;
//saving data in dictionary.
NSDictionary *recipeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization      JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

NSLog(@"My Dictionary is %@", recipeDictionary);
NSMutableArray *contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *contactDict in  [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"contacts"]) {
     Contact *contact = [[Contact alloc] initWithDictionary:contactDict];
      NSLog(@"Name %@",contact.name);  //Prints Name
     [contacts addObject: contact];
}
```

contacts array will contain array of contact objects. You can use dot notation to extract the specific information.
You can pass the contacts array to any part of the app. Objects are better than Dictionaries

Comment: This is great advise; however I don't think the OP has got to the stage of having an `NSDictionary`; he wants to know how to parse JSON in Objective-C (I believe, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Main thing you should do is to convert JSON response to NSString/String
I'd recommend using these libraries for parsing JSON.

Objective-C version:

https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON

Swift version:

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: And why would you recommend using those libraries as opposed to the built-in one?

Comment: Because built-in `NSJSONSerialization` isn't that convenient as these libraries by number of reasons. For example `nil` handling, type detection